# How to install multicore package on R v3.1.2?

Tags: r, multicore, install.packages, r-forge

I am using default command to install `multicore` package

```
install.packages('multicore','http://www.rforge.net/')
```

as written here http://www.rforge.net/multicore/files/ but I recieve warning:

> install.packages('multicore','http://www.rforge.net/')
>   Warning in install.packages :
>     'lib = "http://www.rforge.net/"' is not writable
>   Would you like to use a personal library instead?  (y/n) y
>   Warning in install.packages :
>     package ‘multicore’ is not available (for R version 3.1.2)

Does anybody know any solution to this? I can not use previous versions of R.
I would like to use `mclapply` function from that package.

Thanks for help.

My session info is:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] stringi_0.4-1 ggplot2_1.0.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] colorspace_1.2-4 digest_0.6.8     grid_3.1.2       gtable_0.1.2    
 [5] MASS_7.3-35      munsell_0.4.2    plyr_1.8.1       proto_0.3-10    
 [9] Rcpp_0.11.3      reshape2_1.4.1   scales_0.2.4     stringr_0.6.2   
[13] tools_3.1.2
```

Comment: have you tried only install.packages('multicore') ?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Why do you need it?

Most of its functionality has been integrated into the `parallel` package which already comes with R.  Have a look at its vignette, eg from within R via `vignette()` or else [from here](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/parallel/doc/parallel.pdf).

And the reason you cannot install 'multicore' is because it has been withdrawn by R Core, given how its functionality is (essentially entirely) in 'parallel' now.

Comment: Because `mclapply` is a function that is recommended by hadley wickahm in he's newest book Advanced R.

Comment: But `mclapply` is now part of parallel.

Comment: Whoever just downvoted does a) not understand CRAN packages and b) seems to know better than R Core which packages are needed. Let me repeat: **multicore is retired because it is subsumed in parallel**.

Comment: @MarcinKosinski: Hadley says you're wrong (over IM with me); the book uses `parallel::mclapply`.

Comment: Sorry for trouble. My oversight.

Comment: You should have probably mentioned in the answer that `mclapply` is now part of the `parallel` package.

Comment: I do: "its functionality is (essentially entirely) in 'parallel' now" means that (almost all) functions from `multicore` are in `parallel`.  Plus, OP asked about the package, not the function.  Also see the comments made which re-state this.